# How to make "CD-ROM" emulation using USB mass-storage device?

Tags: usb-drive, data-cd

I have a USB-disk that shows this when connected:

```
[262821.796343] scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            General  USB Flash Disk   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[262821.796697] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     General  USB Flash Disk   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[262821.797535] sr 6:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[262821.797795] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[262821.797961] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[262821.798272] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[262821.798656] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] 13563904 512-byte logical blocks: (6.94 GB/6.47 GiB)
[262821.799182] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[262821.799184] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[262821.800098] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[262821.800106] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[262821.803643]  sdc: sdc1
[262821.808634] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

So the first 1.1 GB is treated as CD-ROM, and the rest as a normal mass-storage device.

How is that made? How can I convert the device to a normal mass-storage device without the "CD-ROM" part?

Comment: Does it say "U3" on the package? They did that, awhile back.

Comment: It is a promotional USB-stick, so no package.

Comment: OK. If it turns out to be U3, see https://superuser.com/questions/600406/format-a-usb-drive-that-has-a-pre-installed-gui